# How to Export Moodle Course format to Dspace?

Tags: moodle, dspace

I need to export courses from Moodle but, but as it is a very closed
application, and the courses are in moodle format, is there any way
to extract the contents / metadata that format to facilitate the
migration to DSpace.

I know, it possible to make on the 'big-hand', but ira spend a lot of
time. For DSpace and moodle use very different and complex databases.

Comment: This is going to depend very much on what it is you're actually wanting to export from Moodle/import into DSpace. Without further details, I doubt anyone will be able to help you with this.

Comment: Not sure if these will help, but there are a couple of Moodle plugins that mention DSpace - https://moodle.org/plugins/repository_sword_upload which looks like it uploads resources? and https://docs.moodle.org/dev/DSpace_Repository_Plugin / https://github.com/enovation/Moodle-Repository-Dspace which looks like it pulls information from DSpace

Answer (score 0):

Moodle exports courses with a .**mbz** extension. Simply rename it to .**zip** and you can extract the XML files from inside. These files will have all the information you need. You could potentially create a tool that programmatically extracts this information and imports it to DSpace.

Also, Moodle is open source, not a closed application. Source available here: https://github.com/moodle/moodle